# Count of positive numbers, using a lookup from data in a pivot table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table, vlookup, countif

Any suggestions on how best to solve this?

I have a pivot table that contains employee IDs with their associated chargeable hours variances on a weekly basis. I can do a simple COUNTIF at the end of each row to total up the number of positive variances in one column and negative variances in another. BUT what I want to do, is move these total columns to a separate sheet (to create a summary view) and use some form of LOOKUP to find the relevant employee ID and give me their totals.

The summary view is a list of all employees (and their IDs in a separate column). Now I want to count the number of positive variances associated with their employee ID in the pivot table and in another column count the number of negative variances.

How do I do this?

Starting with the positive variances, I have tried the following formulas

=IF(NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,Weekly!D:D,0))),COUNTIF(Weekly!$E5:$AZ5,">0"),"")

=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Weekly!D:D,1,FALSE)),"",COUNTIF(Weekly!$E5:$AZ5,">0"))

Both work but they count the variances in the row, instead of counting the variance that relates to the employee ID.

My data is laid out as follows:

A2 is the employee ID (in the new summary sheet that I have created)

Weekly! is the worksheet that contains the variance data

Weekly!D:D contains the employee IDs

Weekly!E:AZ contains the values I want to count

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT((Weekly!D1:D4=A1)*(Weekly!E1:AZ4>0))` ?